# need help with zero sum game

Tags: probability, optimization, game-theory

Tom chooses an integer in {1,2,3} and Bob chooses an integer in {2,3,4}.  If the chosen numbers are the same, no money changes hands If the numbers are different the person who picks the bigger number gets 1 dollar, unless the numbers differ by 1 for which the person picking the smaller number gets 1 dollar.

I used the simplex method here and formulated it into the following problem:

$$
max\ x_1+x_2+x_3\\
subject\ to\ x_2+2x_3\leq 1\\
2x_1+x_3\leq 1\\
2x_1+2x_2\leq 1\\
x\geq 1
$$

I solved the simplex tableau and got it down to reduced form but what do I do after in order to find the value of the game and the optimal strategy?

Comment: What is $x_1$? Hint: Write the payoff matrix of the game first.

Comment: I already did.  I don't quite know what to do next.

Comment: I think it is unlikely that any one here is going try to figure out what is $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$, if you want answers, I suggest to explain your "formulation"

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1, x_2, x_3$ be the fractions of time Tom chooses 1, 2, 3. The correct simplex formulation corresponds to "find values of $\{ x_i \}$ the maximize V by , subject to V not exceeding expectation if Bob chooses 2, nor if Bob chooses 3, nor if Bob chooses 4".  That simplex is
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\mbox{Maximize} V: & \\
& x_1+x_2+x_3 = 1 \\
V \leq &  x_1 - x_3 \\
V \leq &  -x_1 + x_2 \\
V \leq &  -x_1 - x_2 +x_3 \\
\end{array}
$$
The solution is $x_1 = 3/9, x_2 = 2/9, x_3 = 3/9$ and the value is $V = -1/9$.